# SOCKS v5 request sends current user instead of no user

Tags: java, docker, proxy, socks, dante

My questions:

1) How can I use dante as a SOCKS v5 proxy, without authentication to send amqp messages from a producer to RabbitMQ in a docker-compose network?

2) I've never used SOCKS before so I have no idea if what I'm trying to do is stupid or not supposed to work, is it?

I'm currently trying to set up a network with three parts:

1. A proxy server (Dante)
2. A RabbitMQ server.
3. A message producer.

I want to proxy my messages through Dante to rabbitMQ.

To achieve this I've started my producer with the following option:
`-DsocksProxyHost=dante`

I'm running the applications with a docker compose script, and I can verify that my producer connects to the host `dante`. However my producer always tries to connect with the current users credentials, i.e root (or socksuser if I change the user), ignoring the options:
`-Djava.net.socks.username=socksuser
-Djava.net.socks.password=sockspass`

Which I can verify are set with the following output from docker compose:

```
    app_1     | Connecting to proxy host: dante
    app_1     | User: socksuser with password: sockspass
    app_1     |
    dante_1   | Jan 24 15:01:41 (1516806101.263639) sockd[7]: info: pass(1): 
                  tcp/accept [: 172.19.0.4.40910 172.19.0.3.1080
    dante_1   | Jan 24 15:01:41 (1516806101.265226) sockd[7]: info: block(1): 
                  tcp/accept ]: 172.19.0.4.40910 172.19.0.3.1080: 
                  error after reading 11 bytes in 0 seconds: 
                  system password authentication 
                  failed for user "root"

    app_1     | java.net.SocketException: SOCKS : authentication failed
    app_1     |     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:473)
```

The dante docker image I'm using is [wernight/dante](https://hub.docker.com/r/wernight/dante/), with the default configuration provided which states that everyone is allowed to use the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The method to use for SOCKS5 authentication is agreed by negotiation between the SOCKS5 client and the SOCKS5 server prior to actual authentication.

So if the client is initiating authentication, that indicates the server is requiring it, i'd check the SOCKS5 server config.